# How to sort lists of two data fields using two filters

Tags: python, data-structures, data-science

Suppose I have two lists of height and age for **K** people.

For instance,

```
height = [180, 190, 185, 150, 180, 185]
age = [23, 28, 29, 30, 40, 20]
```

First person is 23 years old, and is 180cm tall, second one is 28 years old and 190cm tall, and so on.

I would like to sort these two lists first for height order and then by age, as follows:

```
result = [[150,30], [180,23], [180,40], [185,20], [185,29], [190,28]]
```

Would it be possible? What kind of data structure should I search for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` to pair the data then simply `sorted`

```
height = [180, 190, 185, 150, 180, 185]
age = [23, 28, 29, 30, 40, 20]
result = sorted(zip(height, age))
# [(150, 30), (180, 23), (180, 40), (185, 20), (185, 29), (190, 28)]
```

By default, `sorted` sorts (when item is iterable) by first item, then when collision, by second item and so on, that's exactly what you need

---

So you know, that is how you would do : sort by height, then age in reverse

```
result = sorted(zip(height, age), key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
print(result)  # [(150, 30), (180, 40), (180, 23), (185, 29), (185, 20), (190, 28)]
```